# Function scope if statements

Tags: javascript, scope, execution-time, anti-patterns

I'm experimenting with unusual Javascript 'patterns', and thought of a potentially neat way of scoping blocks if declaring variables in the parent scope is undesirable.

For example, instead of:

```
function someFunction () {
  var x, t;

  for (x = 0; x < 10000; x += 1) {
    if (true) {
      t = x;
    }
  }
}
```

One could save the extra parent variable by using:

```
function someFunction () {
    var x;

    for (x = 0; x < 10000; x += 1) {
      if (true) { void function () {
        var t = x;
      }(); }
    }
}
```

However, my jsperf (  http://jsperf.com/scoped-if ) shows that this, when used repeatedly, may have a negative impact on performance. Clearly this result dictates that the aforementioned isn't a practical pattern, unless executed sparingly.

I understand that the slowness is likely to be the repeated creation and destruction of execution contexts (1 + 10000), whereas the first involves just 1.

My question is, could this pattern still be useful given the above conditions (not used within loops), and why is the creation of contexts so costly?

Comment: I would not try to optimize that, instead optimize what is inside of the loop, normally that takes close to 100% of the time of computing

Comment: Absolutely, the purpose of this 'pattern' is simply to avoid polluting the parent scope with variables only for use within the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) is a reasonable way of emulating [block scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope).

A better way is to use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), with an ES6 transpiler if necessary:

```
function someFunction () {
    var x;

    for (x = 0; x < 10000; x += 1) { 
      if (true) { 
        let t = x;
        // Do something with t here
      }
      // because it is not defined here
    }
    // or here
}
// and even a var wouldn't be defined here
```

[ES6 compatibility table for `let`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#let)

Comment: The reason for emulating block scope using IIFE's is to provide a backwards compatible alternative to the ```let``` keyword. Thanks for providing this as a potential solution, when ES6 is widely implemented, this is definitely the approach to use.

Comment: I think the answer is `let` + Traceur/6to5 or node --harmony/io.js where you can, and IIFEs where you cannot. But not inside loops of unknown length :)